# no login screen after 17.10 install & configure

Tags: system-installation, login, 17.10

I just installed 17.10 on a laptop running 15.10. It's an ASUS Zenbook with core-i7 and GeForce GT 650 M.
After clean install I removed some stuff using apt-get (evolution, games, ...) and ran gnome-tweak-tool.

Now when I boot, I don't reach the login screen. Instead nothing changes on the display after the log message

```
  /dev/sda4/ clean, ... files, ... blocks
```

Comment: your old /home is probably missing the settings needed for wayland and gnome desktop. reinstall them.

Comment: reinstalling packages, confirms that config files was the issue. PS you did what I suggested and reinstalled gnome (ubuntu desktop)

Comment: all desktop config files are in home, and not a violation of user space. where a file is located has nothing to d with whether it is run in user space or kernel space. PS -- root runs in user space.

Comment: This answer disagrees: https://askubuntu.com/questions/993758

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Reinstalling default packages via

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Gave me back the login screen, though in the end not sure which was the relevant package.